# Sorting a list of different objects by shared property in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework

I have class `Message`

```
 public DateTime DateCreated {get; set;}
 public int MessageId {get; set;}
```

I also have class `Activity`:

```
public DateTime DateCreated {get; set;}
public int ActivityId {get; set;}
```

In my db, I use EF to query for both items:

```
db.Messages.ToList();
db.Activities.ToList();
```

I need to take these two lists, push them into a single list, and then sort by DateCreated.  I can use inheritance to make Activity and Message inherit from some generic "Dated" class, but it feels messy, especially since these classes are already inheriting from other classes.

What's the proper way to achieve this?

Comment: Deriving them from a shared interface is a requirement here since you stipulate that they must end up in the same `List`. Even if you do develop an method that sorts `Activity` and `Message` then you will have to upcast them to `object`'s in order for them to both end up in a `List<T>`. This is why people are recommending interfaces.

Comment: Although functional programmers would point out that this would be a situation where a discriminated union would shine if you *desperately* didn't want to upcast to a commmon interface.

Comment: @AdamKewley - thank you.  If speed was the most important criteria while evaluating these options, would interfaces and upcasting still be the best choice?

Comment: Yes, because upcasting is a relatively low overhead operation. You would incur a small performance hit from vtable lookups while using the upcasted form I imagine. A solution resulting in `List<object>` would not necessarily have a large overhead during the sort. However, using the contents afterwards would require a downcast (to either `Activity` or `Message`) which is generally less compiler friendly (it's performed at runtime) and lower performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use interface in this case:

```
public interface IDateCreated 
{
  DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
}
```

implement this interface in your classes and after this you will create

```
var list = new List<IDateCreated>();
list.AddRange(db.Messages.ToList());
list.AddRange(db.Activities.ToList());
var result = list.OrderBy(x => x.DateCreated);
```

Comment: This will return a `List<IDateCreated>`, that means any item can be `Message` or `Activity`, this should be taken into account to cast an  item to the underlying type correctly and access `MessageId` or `ActivityId` accordingly.

Comment: Yeah, if the questioner will need to re-downcast to `Message` or `Activity` they will need to check against the type, which would cost some performance. If upcasting later on is a priority then keeping hold of that type information would be very useful (the information is effectively lost upon downcasting). If performance is super critical, storing the type information in something like an `enum` on `IDateCreated` would prevent the performance overhead of a check like `if (x is Message) ...`

Answer (score 2):

with an interface

```
public interface IDatedObject
{
   DateTime DateCreated {get;}
}
```

Now make both classes implement the interface and store in a list of the interface.

Answer (score 1):

When merging into one list, all elements should have the same type, while you don't have an intermediate type, just try an anonymous type:

```
var list = db.Messages.ToList().Select(x=>new{x.DateCreated, Id = x.MessageId})
             .Concat(db.Activities.ToList().Select(x=>new{x.DateCreated,Id = ActvitiyId})
             .OrderBy(x=>x.DateCreated).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `System.Collections.SortedList` whose add method include a key and value parameter: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.sortedlist%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)